# Firebase Performance | No Data appears in Console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-performance

I've installed and configured Firebase Performance SDK using the following documentation for iOS:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios

However, I noticed that after adding it to my app as well as a simple trace and waiting 24 hours,
performance data is not appearing in the Firebase Console.
Upon further investigation, I noticed I'm receiving the following error message in the XCode console:

[Firebase/Performance][I-PRF300005] URL length exceeds limits, truncating recorded
URL - https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.[mycompany].[app_id]/settings.

So my questions are:
1. How and where does one increase the url limit for crashlytics?
2. Is this the only reason why performance data is not appearing within the Firebase Console?
Any insight and assistance is greatly appreciated regarding this important issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several days of waiting with no changes on my end, performance data did appear.
Also, here's the official response from Firebase support regarding the URL length:

"Our engineers noted that this is working as intended. When URLs are too long, it is not printed out and the max url length that can be is coded is 2000 bytes. This is to guard our system against programming errors. it is also possible that the you’ve encountered a malformed URL or a bad URL request."

Hope this helps someone!